# Python - Getting Scikit-Learn classifier by passing string with the model name as input

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to retrieve a specific SKLearn model object by passing as input a string with the name of the model. For instance, currently I have this to load a MultinomialNB model

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

nb = MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0,
                   class_prior=None,
                   fit_prior=True)
```

I want to have a method such that:

```
def get_model(model_name):
    (...)
    return model
```

so that when I do get_model("MultinomialNB") I get the same object as `nb` for the code above. Anything implemented in Scikit-Learn for this?

Comment: You can create a dictionary where keys are the name and the values are the model. `For example {"MultinomialNB":"MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0,                    class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)", "<name>":"model method"}`

Comment: @Vishal good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `importlib`. It will force you to also pass the module from which to import, though. With this approach, model hyperparameters should also be parametrized in the function call.

Example:

```
import importlib
import sklearn

def get_model(
    model_name: str, import_module: str, model_params: dict
) -> sklearn.base.BaseEstimator:
    """Returns a scikit-learn model."""
    model_class = getattr(importlib.import_module(import_module), model_name)
    model = model_class(**model_params)  # Instantiates the model
    return model
```

which then you could call by doing e.g.

```
model_params = {"alpha": 1.0, "class_prior": None, "fit_prior": True}
nb = get_model("MultinomialNB", "sklearn.naive_bayes", model_params)
```